# Sitecore User Group Oct 2018 Meetup - Queen City, Manchester, NH

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

We are extremely pleased and elated to announce the Oct meetup of the Queen City Sitecore User Group.

Two excellent presentation are lined up for this SUG:

1. Learn what new and powerful features are coming soon in SPE 5.0 - Michael West, Sitecore MVP and Application Architect at Concentra
2. "Solr, Sitecore 9, Shenanigans" - Grant Killian, Sitecore MVP and Solutions Architect at Rackspace

Date & Time (EST):- Wednesday, Oct, 03, 2018 6:00 PM

Date & Time (UTC):- Wednesday, Oct, 03, 2018 10:00 PM

Venue:- SilverTech Inc, 196 Bridge Street, Manchester, NH 03104

[Click here for more details and RSVP.](https://www.meetup.com/Queen-City-Sitecore-User-Group/events/254688424/)